# MAUI Blazor Routing bug?

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, maui, maui-blazor

My routes work fine in a regular Blazor application, but don't in Blazor MAUI.

```
@page "/"
@page "/logitemAdd/{logItemKey?}"
```

My page answers to both of these routes, but in MAUI, the parameter is not getting passed in.

If I remove the first route, the parameter gets passed in.

//////////////////////////////////////

The issue occurs when using NavigateTo.

Here is my Index.razor page.  Note its route of "/Index" and not "/"

```
@page "/Index"
@inject NavigationManager NavMan

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div>
    <a onclick="@navto" href="">test link</a>
</div>

@code{

    public void navto()
    {
        NavMan.NavigateTo("/fetchdata/myVariable");
    }
}
```

Here is my FetchData.razor, note the 2 routes.

When you click on the link in Index the NaviateTo fires, but the parameter is not passed.

If you take the "/" route off the page, the parameter is passed successfully.

```
@page "/"
@page "/fetchdata/{logItemKey?}"
@using MauiApp2.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string logItemKey { get; set; }
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a sample to test and find the route with the parameter can work well.

The code in the razor:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@page "/fetchdata/{logItemKey?}"

<p>@logItemKey</p>
```

The code to get the parameter:

```
@code {
private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

[Parameter]
public string logItemKey { get; set; }
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
}
}
```

And the div in the ui:

```
<div>
    <a href="/fetchdata/test">test link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the "/" route please.  This is where it breaks down.

Comment: I to have reproduced what you have and it works.  I guess I will have to dig deeper to find my issue.  Thank you.

Comment: I have posted code that should reproduce my issue above.

Comment: I have tested your code and it also worked well.@Terrence

Comment: I used the Visual Studio 13.0 Preview 6.0, This may be the only difference between your demo and mine. @Terrence

Comment: This works in a regular Blazor.  It DOES NOT work in MAUI Blazor.  You must be running VS2022 Version 17.4.0 Preview 1.0.  Are you running a MAUI Blazor project?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT, I finally figured it out.  I was checking to see if the param was set in the OnInitializedAsync method.  The paramter IS set in the OnParametersSetAsync method.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it was related to the onclick event never getting raised.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).